# How to specify the network interface for a QUdpSocket to use?

Tags: qt, sockets, udp, broadcast, qudpsocket

I have an application that uses [`QUdpSocket`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html) to send broadcast packets. The machine sending the packets has several network interfaces.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to get `QUdpSocket` to use the right network interface. Is there an option somewhere that allows me to specify exactly which interface to use for sending the packets?

Answer (score 1):

Every subnet has its own broadcast address. So I think you can send broadcast packets 'directly' to the addresses like  10.255.255.255 or 192.168.255.255.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually choosing which network to listen to in the first argument of bind function, address. If you are choosing for example `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` it means that no matter from which interface (better to say as a result of which IP address) the packet is received, the program should catch it. Otherwise you can enter an IP address (or a broadcast address) to which the packet should be sent.

For debugging and verification of it you can use `netstat` to list open ports as explained here:
https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux

In the result of netstat command, `Local Address` is what you are looking for, specifying which address is being listened to.

NOTE: The address of localhost in Local Address (e.g.: 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1) means any Local Address is acceptable.